# Is a product of integrals like distributing a product?

Tags: calculus, integration

Can I argue that:

\begin{align}
\left(\int_a^b f(x) \,dx\right) \left(\int_c^d g(y) \,dy\right)
&= \int_a^b f(x) \int_c^d g(y) \,dy \,dx \\
&= \int_a^b \int_c^d f(x) g(y) \,dy \,dx
\end{align}

since the same would be true for a product of finite sums?

Comment: It follows from $c \int f = \int c f$ for a constant $c$.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks, would you add an answer please?

Comment: :-) ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: In order to do that, keep in mind that 
*$f(x)$ should be independent of $y$ and $g(y)$ should be independent of $x,$ and
*upper and lower limits should be constants as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It follows from the fact that for a constant $c$ we have $c \int f = \int cf$.

Let $c = \int g(y)\, dy$, then $(\int f(x)\,dx) c = \int f(x) c\, dx = \int f(x) (\int g(y) \,d y )\,dx$.

Now look at $f(x) (\int g(y) d y )$ and this time let $c = f(x) $ to get
$f(x) (\int g(y) \,d y ) = \int f(x)g(y)\, d y $, and replacing in the above gives
$(\int f(x)\,dx) (\int g(y)\, dy) = \int \int f(x)g(y) \,dy\, dx$.